# Force Close error on Android Application

Tags: android, forceclose

I have added the Results class to the Android Manifest, so yes, you can cross that off the list.
Is it an error in the way I've set out the method?

```
    package com.kenning.foreveralone;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Results extends Activity{

        EditText fbFriends;
        TextView resulting;
        String value;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.rslt);
            TextView resulting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
            EditText fbFriends = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noFacebookFriends);
            String value = fbFriends.getText().toString();
            resulting.setText("Your score is " + value);
        }



    }
```

When I start this class, it always seems to force close my app.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the log cat:

```
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kenning.foreveralone/com.kenning.foreveralone.Results}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.kenning.foreveralone.Results.onCreate(Results.java:20)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-08 20:05:24.169: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: are you sure there in an element with id = result in the layout file rslt.xml?

Comment: yes, but the TextEdit is in a DIFFERENT xml.

Comment: How come your import does not have any "your package name".R;

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` somewhere in your OnCreate. I am guessing that either the ids are wrong in your rslt.xml layout so result and fbFriends is null, or fbFriends doesn't have any text in it so `getText()` returns null.

Comment: Well, the fbFriends is meant to have a value previous inputted by the user of the app.  The EditText field is located in another xml layout file called frstq.xml.

Comment: The order goes

Mainpage>frstq>scndq>thrdq>frthq>ffthq>sxthq>rslt

rslt contains the result from frstq.  frstq has the EditText and a value is inputted by the user.  They then go through other classes and the point of rslt is to pull that input and print it.

Comment: findViewById will only return a view that is in the current Activity's inflated View. You need to pass the EditText value through the Intent that starts this Activity.

Comment: Ah I see. But how would I go about this if the class is about 5 classes away from the class which prints the result?

Answer (score 0):

It's a *null pointer exception* in onCreate, so why not try *stepping* through `onCreate` to see what variable is null?

That said, I'm guessing `R.id.noFacebookFriends` is not part of the `R.layout.rslt`.

Comment: No, it isn't.  R.id.noFacebookFriends is the EditText from ANOTHER class.

Comment: Which is exactly the problem then. You try to look it up in R.layout.rslt in the code above using findViewById. This will return null. Calling null.getText() will yield the NPE you are experiencing.

Comment: So, can I make this class a subclass of the class with the EditText box so I can obtain the value and NOT get a null pointer exception?

Comment: Put the value from the edittext into a variable you can use later.